# Find Ancestors of a given Node in a Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

I was attempting to solve the question "Find Ancestors of given node". For a fact I was able to solve the question. But I had an add-on question for which I am unable to alter the logic

So lets assume the Binary tree is like below :

```
     100
    /   \
   45    150
  /  \   /  \
40   60 120 200
```

The common ancestor for Node 60 would be 100,45.

My Code :

```
def helper(node,k,path):
    
    if node is None:
        return path
            
    path.append(node.data) # Append every node as we visit
    if path[-1]==k: #Once we find the desired Node, print the list till last element
        print(path[:-1])

    path = helper(node.left,k,path)
    
    path = helper(node.right,k,path)
    
    del path[-1] #while backtracking , remove the leaf node
    
    return path
    
def findCommonAns(root,k):
    if root is None:
        return None
    
    if root.data == k:
        return [root.data]
    helper(root,60,[])
    

findCommonAns(tree.root,60)
```

My add-on question is, instead of printing, if I wanted to return the list (path), how can I modify this logic ? As I am learning recursion for just a week now, I am finding it hard to modify the above logic.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: @ggorlen , Actually I want to understand how to modify the above logic, so that instead of printing I can return the list.

Comment: partially yes, But I tried passing path list from findCommonAns to the helper method and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Your example tree happens to be a BST. Is this always the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def helper(node,k,path):
    #If node is empty, that is if either root is None,
    #or if we have gone beyon leaf node, result the path list
    if node is None:
        return path
            
    path.append(node.data) #Append data as we visit
    if path[-1]==k:#If last item of the list is the node
        return path[:-1] # return the elemenet till the last element

    path = helper(node.left,k,path)
    
    path = helper(node.right,k,path)
    
    del path[-1]
    
    return path
    

def findCommonAns(root,k):
    if root is None:
        return None
    
    if root.data == k:
        return [root.data]
    path=[]
    helper(root,k,path)
    return path[:-1]

findCommonAns(tree.root,60)
```